# Why docker compose volume creates directory by default?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Consider this `dockerc-compose.yml` file:

```
version "3.9"
services:
  site:
    image: siteimage:latest
    volumes:
       /infra:/infra
       /site:/site
       /branding/logo.png:/branding/logo.png
```

The point is that if `logo.png` does not exist in my local PC, docker creates a directory for it in the container, instead of doing nothing.

Why docker behave this way? How can I change it? How can I tell docker to either not create a directory when the local directory does not exist, or tell it to create file instead of a directory?

Note: We're creating `docker-compose.yml` file dynamically through a tool. Thus please don't comment **you already know if logo.png exists or not**. Thank you.

Comment: I don't uderstand what is the behavior you expect. Should the creation of the service fail if the directory of the volume doesn't exist ? And how a png file could be created automatically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, either generates it as folder or generates error:
[Read Docs: Differences between -v and --mount behavior](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#differences-between--v-and---mount-behavior)

So write a bash script checking for that file and if it is a folder, remove it and write a dummy file. Then call this script from docker entrypoint and after that your real process..